# Performance issue of dynamically adding point to a C# chart

Tags: c#, charts, mschart

I have a big chart has more than 16000+ points. While dynamically adding a point to the end of the chart, the chart was thus facing a heavy redraw job. When the data frequency is rather high, the chart is almost dead and CPU is on full load.

Do you have any idea to optimize this performance?

Is there any possibility to have the chart redraw only the new part not the whole chart? I just simply use AddXY to add new point the set. I can see that as long as I add the dynamic code the program get stucked.

```
fullChart.Series["LastPriceSeries"].Points.AddXY(time, mktData.LastPrice);
fullChart.Series["HighSeries"].Points.AddXY(time, mktData.AskPrice1);
fullChart.Series["LowSeries"].Points.AddXY(time, mktData.BidPrice1);
fullChart.Series["VolumeSeries"].Points.AddXY(time, volume);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since we don't see your work, it is impossible to answer your question.

Answer (score 4):

There are several tips to optimize MSCharts.

Please try to enclose the portion of code where you add a point by

```
mySerie.Points.SuspendUpdates();
...
mySerie.Points.ResumeUpdates();
```

16000 points is a lot. A good optimization technique consists in using a decimation algorithm that limits the amount of displayed points to the actual width of the graph.

I suggest to keep all the points needed in an array, for example, then resample it to another smaller array using moving average or simply bypassing an amount points. It's a very fast process.

Then, the resulting array can bound directly to a MSChart serie.

Comment: There are so many tips to optimize the MSCharts, this one must be the very first :D

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this does not hit the target. I think the major problem is that drawing a chart with 16000+ really takes time. Every second I would add two more points, which would also require the chart to redraw itself. I'd think of other ways like leveling the point.